# Terraform - create S3 buckets with name; leave existing buckets alone

Tags: terraform

In our development environment we want to have S3 buckets for each developer. I'm trying to migrate the management of these buckets to Terraform. This is taking place in a new account, so there are no buckets existing at start.

```
locals {
  buckets = flatten( [
    for e in var.environments : [
      for a in var.apps : [
        for d in var.developers: [
          "macguffin-${a}-${e}${d != "" ? "-${d}" : "" }"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  count = length(local.buckets)
  bucket = element(local.buckets, count.index)
  
  tags = {
    Name = element(local.buckets, count.index)
    Environment = "development"
  }
}

# further configuration of bucket removed
```

If I set the list of developers to be ["bob"], do a terraform apply, then I get the expected buckets created and configured.

If I now add "mary", so that the developer list is ["bob", "mary"]; it will create the buckets for mary, but it will also destroy and recreate the buckets for bob.

Can this be avoided? I don't want to mess with Bob's buckets unless I remove him from the list of developers. I can see that the "bucket" property on the aws_s3_bucket resource is documented as forcing re-creation, but I cannot see how to define a bucket without invoking this forced re-creation.

I have tried to only give TF a working list of developers (e.g., ["Mary"], but then it wants to remove Bob's buckets.

## Updates

Ilya Khrustalev has the right answer, but I think it might be helpful to explain why it's helpful and why I was getting the issue that I was.

When using lists/count, the important thing is the index of each bucket id. So, if I was creating just a single bucket, and added Mary's bucket before Bob's, then index 0 has the bucket name "macguffin-app-dev-mary" where it previously had the name "macguffin-app-dev-bob". The change in bucket name is what causes the bucket to be recreated. (I had too much stuff in my local example, so I was missing that this was the message).

It appears that switching to maps/sets for the input and using the for_each causes terraform to use the key name rather than the position in the collection.

My takeaway would be to use set & for_each for collections like this. It will work with lists, but you have to be very certain that the order of elements does not change and that anything new goes on the end. In my example, I was able to get the expected behavior by swapping the iteration of environments and developers and always adding Mary to the end of the developers list. I think that using the set is just going to be much less prone to error as time goes by.

One more thing, subsequent reference to the created buckets should also use a for_each; eg:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "versioning" {
  for_each = aws_s3_bucket.s3
  bucket = each.value.bucket
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

[for_each docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each)

Comment: What is the plan snippet that states the reason for bucket deletion? There are a few other issues present in the question, but none of them are likely to be related to the root cause of your core issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `for_each` statement + `toset()` function in order to allow Terraform accurately track keys of created buckets.

Here is an example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  for_each = toset(locals.buckets)
  bucket = each.key
  
  tags = {
    Name = each.key
    Environment = "development"
  }
}
```